# Mongo db connection: Throw error for Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I want to use Mongo db for which I am running this command:
node server.js within the terminal of my VS code.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/la/Desktop/success/server.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

I have created a **server.js** file within the pages folder of my Nextjs project.

I have installed node. Where am I going wrong?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
//Success

const MONGODB_URI =‘ xxxxxx’
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/Ab’, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose
    .connection
    .om('connected', () => {
        console.log('Mongoose is connected');

    })

//Schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    date: {
        type: String,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

//Model
const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', BlogPostSchema);

//Saving data to our mongoDB
const data = {
    title: 'welcome',
    body: 'first post'
};

const newBlogPost = new BlogPost(data);
newBlogPost.save((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Somethign happened");
    } else {
        console.log("data saved");
    }

});

//HTTP request logger
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        username: 'caa',
        age: 5
    };
    res.json(data);

});

app.get('/api/name', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        username: 'caa',
        age: 5
    };
    res.json(data);

});

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: You need to provide code for this to get an answer

Comment: I have updated with the code @whoami

Comment: It says it's not able to find server.js, where are you executing ?

Comment: You are not providing the proper path of server.js file. You are executing the command from success folder but server.js file is in your pages folder. So, provide the proper path and it will work.

Comment: The issue was in the path which got resolved